# Calculating lag days with customer id and date in R

Tags: r

I have the following code :

```
Cust <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3)
Date <- as.Date(c("2017-06-24   ","2017-07-10","2017-07-10","2017-07-10","2017-07-11","2017-07-15","2017-07-15","2017-07-15","2017-06-19","2017-07-19","2017-10-20","2018-01-01"))
TCode <- c(123,123,125,125,124,231,231,234,236,332,345,443)
SKU <- c("A","B","C","D","E","FF",'G',"H","J","GG","HH","JJ")
df <- data.frame(Cust,Date,TCode,SKU)
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(Cust) %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  mutate(lag1 = lag(Date), difference = Date - lag1) %>%
  arrange(Cust,Date)
```

The output generated from this is as follows :

[image]

I want the difference should be calculated from the initial day if the we get the same day again for unique customer.
For example, when `Cust = 1` and initial date is `'2017-06-24'`then the lag difference at day `' 2017-07-10` is 16. But the next transaction was also on the same day but now the difference is 0. It should not be 0, it should be 16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After taking difference between current date and previous date for each `Cust`, we can `group_by` `Date` and replace 0's with first `diff` `Date`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(Cust, Date) %>%
  group_by(Cust) %>%
  mutate(diff = as.integer(Date - lag(Date))) %>%
  group_by(Date, .add = TRUE) %>%
  #In old dplyr use add = TRUE
  #group_by(Date, add = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(diff = replace(diff, diff == 0, first(diff)))


#    Cust Date       TCode SKU    diff
#   <dbl> <date>     <dbl> <chr> <int>
# 1     1 2017-06-24   123 A        NA
# 2     1 2017-07-10   123 B        16
# 3     1 2017-07-10   125 C        16
# 4     1 2017-07-10   125 D        16
# 5     1 2017-07-11   124 E         1
# 6     2 2017-06-19   236 J        NA
# 7     2 2017-07-15   231 FF       26
# 8     2 2017-07-15   231 G        26
# 9     2 2017-07-15   234 H        26
#10     3 2017-07-19   332 GG       NA
#11     3 2017-10-20   345 HH       93
#12     3 2018-01-01   443 JJ       73
```